# slick slider adaptive height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using slick slider, I have my ul & li items and I have set the slider to use adaptiveHeight as my slide content will be different heights, I'm having an issue as I want one of my slides to load content when a user clicks a 'loadmore' button however when the user clicks the button the loaded content is not resizing the slide height. Is there a way of making a slide NOT use the adaptiveHeight value?

this is what I have for my slider currently.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.your-class').slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    pauseOnFocus: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    speed: 1800,
    cssEase: 'ease',
    easing: 'swing'
  });
});
```

Comment: have you seen this example on codepen? do you mean like this where one of the slides can be taller than the rest? https://codepen.io/simonmshirley/pen/remoXb

Comment: my content will most likely have a large height and I don't want to set a large height which will have no content until the user clicks 'load more'

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when  uused the `slidesSlider` by default slick.cc add the height to the child div. `slick-slide slick-current slick-active` gives `height: auto` to the current div but must apply on custom class.

```
<div class="slick-list slid-chil">
.slid-chil{
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that when `slidesToShow` is set to 1, then `adaptiveHeight` does not work on mobile/small breakpoints. It seems to set a fixed height on this div.

```
<div class="slick-list draggable">
```

Comment: FYI - This isn't a complete answer and might get voted down as a result. If there is a part of the question code that needs to be different, you should post the correct code. This currently appears like you are giving a hint as to what the problem was and how to resolve it and not the complete solution.

Comment: Feel free to reference [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It is often more helpful if you include at least a brief explanation along with your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I had a similar issue. Make sure the "slick-initialized" parent class doesn't have any other class. I had a class which had styles that interfered with slick.